# HG: Undo a commit from history

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a HG repository with revs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

When I committed rev 4, I unknowingly botched some changes in rev3 that I should not have. I did not notice this until rev 6 was already committed.

I need to undo changes in rev 4, but then re-apply all other changes after that. Basically undoing commit #4. How can I do that?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want [hg backout](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout)

> Revert/undo the effect of an earlier [changeset](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangeSet)...
>
> Backout works by applying a changeset that's the opposite of the changeset to be backed out. That new changeset is committed to the [repository](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Repository), and eventually merged...

Comment: Once I use backout though, how do I re-apply changesets 5 & 6, that have respectively been reversed due to rollback? Thats the part I'm confused on. Any tips?

Comment: backout creates a new changeset after 5,6 that is effectively the inverse of 4. you wouldn't need to re-apply 5 and 6

Comment: `hg backout -r 4` will reverse the changes made in revision 4, without touching the changes made in revisions 5 and 6.  The help system provides a good overview (http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/backout).

Comment: backout worked. Here's the command I used: hg backout --merge -r 4 --parent 3

Comment: It could be very good if you add more info in your answer, not only a link. For example, you can add @TimHenigan comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the MQ extension:

```
hg qinit
hg qimport -r 4:tip
hg qpop -a
hg qdelete 4.diff
hg qpush -a
hg qfinish -a
```

The above is how you rewrite history, which is what you want I believe.

You can also use `hg backout` but that undoes a commit in your working directory and you can commit that.

Comment: This is what I would do *if and only if* I knew the last time a changeset from my repository was shared with anyone else was changeset 3 or earlier. Otherwise you have a nasty little merge headache coming as you introduce new versions of the same changes in changesets 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: That is a given. Rewriting history is always a last resort, especially when you are are sharing it.