# hg remove * deleted my files! How do I get them back?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Folks, I need your help!

I tried to push my hg repository to bitbucket for the first time. It didn't work and I thought this was because the project is to huge. Therefore, I wanted to push only one single file.
Since I did "hg add *" before, I wanted to revoke this, and typed "hg remove *" and now it DELETED FILES ON MY COMPUTER. But not all of them, only some...

I need these files back, how do I do it? Please tell me they're not gone, please please please.

Thank you so much for your help!!

This is my command history:

```
  518  hg commit commit_test.txt -m "first commit"
  519  hg add commit_test.txt
  520  hg commit -m "test"
  521  ls -ll
  522  ls -la
  523  cd .hg/ 
  524  ls
  525  ls -la
  526  pico hgrc
  527  cd ..
  528  hg status
  529  hg add commit_test.txt~ 


  530  hg add commit_test.txt
  531  hg commit -m "blabla"
  532  hg push
  533  hg add commit_test.txt
  534  hg commit -m "maaan"
  535  hg status
  536  hg remove *
  537  hg status
  538  hg commit -m "bla"
  539  ls
  540  hg add test.txt 
  541  hg commit -m "test"
  542  hg push
  543  hg revert
  544  hg revert --all
  545  history
  546  hg add *
  547  hg add -r *
  548  hg help add
  549  hg add -S *
  550  cd gui_relabel/
  551  hg add *
  552  cd images/
  553  hg add *
  554  cd ..
  555  hg revert all
  556  hg revert *
  557  history
```

Here is what hg log gives me:

$ hg log

```
  changeset:   6:4726f671ae96
  tag:         tip
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Wed Dec 04 12:21:30 2013 +0100
  summary:     test

  changeset:   5:55b3158def38
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Wed Dec 04 12:17:19 2013 +0100
  summary:     bla

  changeset:   4:ae0dd836586d
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Wed Dec 04 12:14:50 2013 +0100
  summary:     blabla

  changeset:   3:0249fdc26fa7
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Wed Dec 04 12:13:59 2013 +0100
  summary:     test

  changeset:   2:40bdcf4d2104
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Wed Dec 04 12:12:37 2013 +0100
  summary:     first commit test

  changeset:   1:f9e20020ca1d
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Sun Nov 10 14:54:46 2013 +0100
  summary:     first commit

  changeset:   0:7a8edcee06ff
  user:        KG <...@gmail.com>
  date:        Mon Nov 04 20:36:41 2013 +0100
  summary:     blabla
```

Comment: Can you do a `hg log` and post the results in your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HG: Undo a commit from history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913424/hg-undo-a-commit-from-history)

Comment: Could you please still tell me, which command to use? I'm too afraid to mess everything up and have those files deleted forever...

Comment: Please come [chat with us on IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mercurial). That is the place where you will get the best interactive help for Mercurial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could run

```
hg backout 5
```

You can read [more about backout](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout) if you like

Answer (score 10):

Your files are not gone. Mercurial does not throw away data, that is one of the first rules of the system.

To explain what `hg remove` did to your files, let us look at the cases one by one. A file in your working copy can be in one out of a handful different states: it can be modified, added, removed, missing, unknown, ignored, or clean.

I've prepared a working copy that looks like this:

```
$ hg status --all
M a
A b
R c
! d
? e
I f
C g
```

The files `a` to `g` are in the seven states I mentioned above. We can now talk about what happens when you try to remove these files:

- A **modified** file (`a`) is not removed:

  ```
  $ hg remove a
  not removing a: file is modified (use -f to force removal)
  ```
- An **added** file (`b`) is also not removed:

  ```
  $ hg remove b
  not removing b: file has been marked for add (use forget to undo)
  ```
- A **removed** file (`c`) is no longer present in the working copy, so nothing more happens.
- A **missing** file (`d`) is no longer present in the working copy, so nothing more happens.
- An **untracked** file (`e`) is not removed:

  ```
  $ hg remove e
  not removing e: file is untracked
  ```
- An **ignored** file (`f`) is not removed (since it is not tracked):

  ```
  $ hg remove f
  not removing f: file is untracked
  ```
- A **clean** file (`g`) *is* removed.

The only type of file that `hg remove` will actually remove from your working copy is a clean file. A clean file is already committed, so the content is safely stored in the repository. You can get it back with `hg revert`:

```
$ hg revert g
$ hg status --all
M a
A b
R c
! d
? e
I f
C g
```

The file `g` is back with the same content as it had before you removed it.