# Surgically removing commits in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have accidentally committed multiple large data files (commits 3 and 4 in the example below) to my default branch in Mercurial and added commits on top without noticing. I want to surgically remove those commits. Fortunately, no code was touched in those commits so it should seem possible to easily remove them. I can't use **Strip** because it will remove all child commits too. How can I remove them?

For example, I want to remove revision 3 and 4 entirely in the screenshot below. You can find the example [repository here](https://bitbucket.org/danieljfarrell_teraview/surgically_removing_commits/src/default/) in case it helps!
[image: Version control screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HG: Undo a commit from history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913424/hg-undo-a-commit-from-history)

Comment: @DaveInCaz - obviously "no". For big files (or "totally confidential") backout isn't option, because a) does not reduce size of repo b) does not eliminate all history of secrets from repo

Comment: @LazyBadger its the question that is the duplicate. There are more than one way to solve a problem like this, and multiple additional answers there would improve that question. It would be better to add another good answer over there and then this gets closed.

Comment: It’s significantly different for the points raised by @LazyBadger  and also a better written question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rebase last two changesets into *some another* location, strip unwanted changesets, return wanted back into DAG
2. Generic case for "wanted and unwanted files in old changeset": install `evolve` extension, [uncommit files](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#example-9-uncommit-files-from-an-older-changeset-discard-changes)